# Yii2 вопросы по advanced шаблону

Tags: yii2

Поясните какое что в  `advanced` шаблоне, или подтвердите что я правильно понял суть шаблона.

1. Зачем вот эта фишка с инициализацией проекта. Если можно просто было положить
   конфиг в папке дев и продакшин и просто переключать в индексе с
   какой папки читать конфиг.
2. Что переключиться в другой режим нужно просто выполнить инит с другим режимом? И оно само перепишет индексы и конфиг с енвайромента в папки проекта?
3. Вопшем розясните для чего нужна эта фишка с инициализацией и окружениями если можно просто сразу сделать конфиг и нужные в нужных местах и просто переключать режим в индекс файле к примеру.

Comment: Вопрос актуален?

Comment: Сегодня просто в индексе переключаешь, завтра еще в одном файле, потом права на директории установить надо и т.д. Проще все зашить в инициализацию и выполнить одной командой. И никогда не забудешь, если в скрипте прописано.